# Fingerprint comparison with php

Tags: php, webserver, fingerprint, biometrics

I have a small device which scans fingerprints. There i have an image of the fingerprint. I hope i can get some "Bio-ID" of this fingerprint image and send this id to a server. The server side can only execute php.

There i like to compare this "Bio-ID". In the best case no php libraries are required and the "Bio-ID" just can be compared as a string. I like to authenticate a user, which means i have to compare the fingerprints.

It would work like on this picture described:

[image]

Is is important that on the server side it is only possible to use php (no special configuration), so it would be great if the fingerprint could be sent as a string and this string can be compared to other strings without much effort.

Thank you very much

Comment: OK... and what do you want us to help you with? Doesn't your device come with documentation of some sort? We don't even know *what* device you bought.

Comment: I use a usb fingerprint scanner. It just return a bitmap of the fingerprint. Currently i do not have anything else than a bitmap. Comparable to an input image of: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sourceafis/ The fingerprint scanner is a Futronic FS88h

Comment: Why not make it return a template that you can then store and compare against later? http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_sdk_ansi.html

Comment: @Kevin Did you find any PHP lib for this and comparison on server side?

Comment: I did use a C# service which is called from the php code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I am assuming your question is "What are the next steps I need to do in order to get this system to work".

Well since you already have a scanner (Futronic FS88h), which gives you a bitmap, then you have to pass this bitmap through an algorithm that changes it into a string. You mentioned that in the best case scenario you wish not to use a library, however that will be more complicated for you if you didn't. A library is a collection of code that someone has already developed for a specific purpose. If you don't want to use a function someone else created to get your fingerprint string from your bitmap, you will have to create it yourself, which is a million times more difficult.

My suggest would be:

1. find a library that has the algorithm in it to change a fingerprint into a string.
2. install that library into the server you are using
3. create the php functions that then

   - Stores these fingerprint values into a database or whichever is your preferred method of storage
   - Compares a users fingerprint with all the fingerprints in storage
   - Deletes fingerprints stored

That should help you move forward

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A library can be used on the client side. Also simple libraries may be installed on the server. Unfortunately only "clean" php-libraries, because e.g. native libraries cannot be installed on the hosted webserver. Unfortunately i did not find a usefull library which produces an output which can be compared on the server side with php.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do the comparison like string comparison. It is possible, only if you have the same fingerprint image again and again. But in the reality, When you have the fingerprint two times, both the images will be different from each other with little bit position change, angle change, and quality of the scan. So String comparison is not possible.

All the scanners do provide the SDK for capturing the fingerprint and comparing them (1:1) which you can use for developing the desktop application. If you need to compare the scanned images at the server, then you need to implement your own Automatic Finger Identification algorithm or you have to use third party services such as

1. [CAMS](http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint)
2. [M2Sys](http://www.m2sys.com)
3. [Neurotechnology](https://www.neurotechnology)